# overflow-y scroll not working for ul nested in div

Tags: html, css

There must be something special required to get `overflow-y: scroll` to work, and I'm unable to find it... Any ideas?

https://jsfiddle.net/tmnx2z0u/

HTML:

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      One
    </li>
    <li>
      One
    </li>
    <li>
      One
    </li>
    <li>
      One
    </li>
    <li>
      One
    </li>
    <li>
      One
    </li>
    <li>
      One
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  background-color: #FFFFEE;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

ul {
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you want to add `overflow-y: scroll` to `div` instead of `ul`?

Comment: @CommercialSuicide - because that makes the entire div scroll down and not just the UL

Comment: You can wrap `ul` in auxiliary `div` and set scroll to it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove overflow-y: hidden from the div container element.

Add an explicit height to the ul.

```
div {
  background-color:#FFFFEE;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  //overflow-y: hidden;
}

ul {
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: As per OP's comment, it appears they just want the UL to scroll, not the whole div. This answer does what OP asks and should be marked correct.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the div overflow-y to scroll and removing the ul styling worked for me:

```
div {
  background-color:#FFFFEE;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

/* you don't need this.
ul {
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
*/
```

---

EDIT: As per OP's comment, only the UL should scroll. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45516821/2734279) answer accomplishes that. My answer will scroll the entire contents of the div.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the ul css to:

```
  ul {
  margin: auto;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  }
```

By adding 'height' property that equal to the parent element, and 'margin' to 'auto'.

https://jsfiddle.net/7j428j5g/

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and placed `height: 100%` but it didn't resolve but by specifying the hardcoded value resolved the problem `height: 200px`.

The Other way to maintain the value `height: 100%` is by placing `height` property all the parent elements.